# Pass object with route ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4

I am new to IONIC 4 and I want to pass an object from one screen to another screen. My first screen is screen1 and I want to pass "model" object of type "any" from screen1 to screen2.

Currently i am navigating from my screen1 to screen2 using below code.

> this.router.navigateByUrl('screen2/');

How can i pass "model" object with this route?

I searched on google for a solution but I found nothing related my question. I just found only one thing that we can pass data with URL using queryparams but I want to keep data private and don't want to show data in URL.

Anyone knows, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to you is to implement a [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Take a look at my [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-provide-pipe-in-component) at StackBlitz to see it in action

Implementing a resolver:

```
@Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<Team> {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    // return the data you need in your component using your service 
    // route params will sit in - route.params.id
  }
}
```

---

Declaring it:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: TeamResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [TeamResolver]
})
class AppModule {}
```

---

Using it:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class TeamCmp {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    // the data sits here - this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by using navigate of Router

```
    this.router.navigate(['screen2', {modelName: model}]);
```

and receive by ActivatedRoute

```
    this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('modelName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question was 'how do I send stuff from one page to another', the solution needn't be constrained to using the router: another alternative is using storage.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

blah() {
    this.storage.set('importantThing', this.importantThing);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('my-page/new-subpage');
}
```

And then in the receiving page:

```
await this.storage.get('importantThing').then(result => {
      this.importantThing= result;
      console.log('my importantThing is', this.importantThing);
    });
```

Just throwing it out there as an alternative. It's pretty useful the way my app is structured. The item will persist behind the scenes in storage until you delete it. Also may be useful, or not. Depends on what you need, I suppose! Hope it's useful.